# Spacing of ordinary atoms in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, letterspacing

Is there a way to generically enlarge the spacing between simple symbols in mathmode (not asking for spacing around operators nor for individually applying commands such as `\!` for each whitespace)? Microtype's `\textls{}` and `\lsstyle` seem to only work for textparts of an equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\hat{H} = \frac12 m\omega_\text{m}^2 \hat x_\text{m}^2+\frac{\hat p_{\text{m}}^2}{2m}
$

\textls[500]{%
$\displaystyle
\hat{H} = \frac12 m\omega_\text{m}^2 \hat x_\text{m}^2+\frac{\hat p_{\text{m}}^2}{2m}
$
}
\end{document}
```

To further clarify, I am looking for a way to modify the space between *ordinary atoms* as they seem to be called.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Herbert Voss's` beautiful explanation about `mathmode`, https://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=en and refer page number 30 about spacing in `math` by using the tags `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and  `\thickmuskip`

Comment: Isn't that only valid for operators? I'm referring to the space between 3 and _x_ in their example in Tab. 6 on p. 31 (or the space between, e.g., 2 and  _m_ in the denominator in my example).